# What source did Thomas Medwin use for the argument of his translation of Prometheus Bound?

Tags: identification-request, august-wilhelm-schlegel

In a [footnote](https://books.google.com/books?id=6DoBAAAAMAAJ&pg=PR7#v=onepage&q&f=false) to his translation of Aeschylus's *Prometheus Bound* (1832), Thomas Medwin says,

> I make no apology for taking this argument from Black’s translation of Schlegel’s admirable treatise on dramatic literature.

The Schlegel is Friedrich von Schlegel, but I don't know which of his works is being cited, nor who the translator, Black, is. Who is Black and how do I cite his translation?

The closest citation I can find is in a [list of translations of August Wilhelm von Schlegel's works](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schlegel-aw/#EnglTran):

> 1944 (1833), *A.W. Schlegel’s Lectures on German literature from Gottsched to Goethe,* Oxford: B. Blackwell (notes taken by George Toynbee).

But this was published the year after the Medwin source and is by Blackwell, not Black.

I'll owe bonus gratitude if you can point me to an archive of Black's translation online.

Answer (score 4):

Ah, I found it in the process of researching for this question.

The "Black" is John Black and his translation is *A Course on Dramatic Art and Literature by August Wilhelm Schlegel*, in two volumes, published by Baldwin, Cradock and Joy (in London), Blackwood (in Edinburgh) and John Cumming (in Dublin) in 1815, and available on [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=6CMwAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA112).

Comment: The Internet Archive is probably more convenient as they have OCR'd text too — [volume 1](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.45955), [volume 2](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.40717).